# Add header to csv before converting to shapefile

Tags: python, csv, header

I have a code that converts csv files to shapefiles, but because my csv files do not have a header, the first line of data is replaced by the header in shp.writer. How can I add a header to the csv file before it is written as a shapefile?

```
import glob
import csv
import shapefile as shp
#lon, lat, count = [],[],[]
for filename in glob.glob('/data/kbrown/GLM/plots/test/hold/*.csv'):
    revFilename = 
    filename.replace('/data/kbrown/GLM/plots/test/hold/*.csv',"")
    rev2Filename = revFilename.replace(".csv","")
    out_file = rev2Filename + '_temp.shp'
    print(out_file)

    with open(rev2Filename + '.csv') as f:
#    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = ["Lat", "Lon", "Count"], delimiter = ";")
#    writer.writeheader()
    next(f)
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    lon, lat, count = [],[],[]
    for row in r:
        lon.append(float(row[0]))
        lat.append(float(row[1]))
        count.append(int(row[2]))
#            f.close()
#        print(lon)
    w = shp.Writer(shapeType=shp.POINT)
#    w.autoBalance = 1
    w.field('lon', "F",10,10)
    w.field('lat',"F",10,10)
    w.field('count',"N",10)
    w.autoBalance = 1
    for j,k in enumerate(lat):
        w.point(lon[j],lat[j])
        w.record(lon[j], lat[j], count[j])
    w.save(out_file)
    w.shp.close()
    w.shx.close()
    w.dbf.close()
```

Example of csv before:

```
-135            0               13646        
-135.2443500000 0.5356640000    44
-135.4915900000 1.0737620000    35
-135.7417600000 1.6142580000    24
-135.9949100000 2.1571150000    21
-136.2510900000 2.7022940000    18
```

Example of output:

```
lon          lat        count 
-135.244353  0.535664   44
-135.491592  1.073762   35
-135.741763  1.614258   24
-135.994915  2.157115   21
-136.251098  2.702294   18
```

As you can see, the first line of data is deleted, and replaced by the header. How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the indenting in your code. Also, you could include a short example of one of the CSV files.

Comment: @MartinEvans I have made the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: I received the following error, TypeError:fieldnames is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

Switch to `DictReader(...`

```
    r = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames = ["Lat", "Lon", "Count"], delimiter = ",")

    lon, lat, count = [], [], []
    for row in r:
        lon.append(float(row['Lon']))
        lat.append(float(row['Lat']))
        count.append(int(row['Count']))
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I received the following error, TypeError:fieldnames is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

Comment: @KaylaBrown: Sorry my bad. Updated my Answer-

Comment: @stovl Unfortunately this did not work. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @KaylaBrown: Rereading your code I see you have  a `next(f)` Line bevor the `for r ...` this will skip the **First Line**. Remove it.
`

Comment: @stovl, Thank you for the advice, I will be sure to specify in future posts. Removing next(f) corrected the error. Thanks for your help.